# XSL number() cannot preserve decimals

Tags: function, xslt, numbers

I have below XSL `value-of` tag in my XSL file which is trying to add huge numbers, but I need to preserve 3 decimal points, will number function be able to handle the decimal percision?  Currently its not.

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="xx:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'v6t1', number(xx:get_variable($_xx, 'v6t1')) + number(xx:normalize_string($_xx, (.//.)[1])))"/>
```

Comment: Have you got an example?

Comment: like after adding up i m supposed to get something like this 81934279377189.163, but i m only getting 81934279377189.16

Comment: What are your values in v6t1 and the other elements?

Comment: The value of v6t1 will be something like this 3452126436925.381

Comment: Decimal *places.* Not that floating-point values have them. 'Decimals' is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number() function converts strings to IEEE double-precision floating point values, which retain about 16 decimal digits of accuracy. This is consistent with the rounding error you are seeing.

XSLT 2.0 offers a decimal data type which will typically maintain greater accuracy than this.

Comment: Thank you, for replying, so instead of number, i can use decimal()

Comment: Yes, if you've got XPath 2.0/XSLT 2.0, then you can use xs:decimal(). The number of digits in xs:decimal precision is actually implementation-defined. Saxon supports "infinite" precision.